# Cloud Page .ics file unable to be opened in safari

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, calendar

I have an email with a button that has ampscript `RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(x))`.
After redirecting, it automatically downloads .ics file.
I am having problem when trying to get the ics file to download on safari.

Safari pops up saying

> "This website is trying to show you a calendar invite. Do you want to
>   allow this?"

And once I click allow, it says

> "Safari cannot download this file"

The .ics file downloads fine on desktop and android.
My cloud page consist of ssjs to call `httpheader` then ics file properties. Has anyone come across the same instance and were able to resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the CloudPage itself, but to the ICS file and the attributes it comes with.

Apparently Safari is very restrictive in what it allows to download and without seeing your ICS content code I'm not able to give you exact instructions, but check the following details:

- Use: `'Content-type': 'text/calendar; charset=utf-8'`
- Use: `'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename=name.ics'`
- Remove `target="_blank"` if you have it